# problem with fileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I have two applications, `CREATOR` (which I can't modify) and `OBSERVER`. CREATOR manipulates many files, and I need OBSERVER to know when that happens. I wrote OBSERVER in C#, and I'm using `FileSystemWatcher`. I set path to my path, set filter to `FILE` and add all the necessary events. But when CREATOR modifies the file, no event is raised in OBSERVER. Oddly, when I modify the file by hand, OBSERVER *does* see the change. I thought that maybe CREATOR doesn't free the file, but when I close CREATOR, OBSERVER still doesn't see the change.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Extra details:
When CREATOR modifies the file, I can delete it by hand, or when I open the file I see that all changes are saved.

## edit

my fileSystemWatcher object setting:

```
fileSystemWatcherObs.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
fileSystemWatcherObs.Filter = "kbd.dbf";
fileSystemWatcherObs.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
fileSystemWatcherObs.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Attributes |
    NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.Security |
    NotifyFilters.Size;
fileSystemWatcherObs.Path = "D:\\FOLDER";
fileSystemWatcherObs.SynchronizingObject = this;
fileSystemWatcherObs.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(  this.fileSystemWatcherObs_Changed );
fileSystemWatcherObs.Created += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler( this.fileSystemWatcherObs_Created );
fileSystemWatcherObs.Deleted += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler( this.fileSystemWatcherObs_Deleted );
fileSystemWatcherObs.Renamed += new System.IO.RenamedEventHandler( this.fileSystemWatcherObs_Renamed );
```

and of course method for this events

Comment: Please read this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: So you have one application that modifies files, and you wrote and application with filesystemwatcher to check for those modifications, but it doesn't notice when your "creator" application modifies them?  Please post the relevant code from your "observer" application.

Comment: yes, exactly. I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/08/12/10195186.aspx. But I'm not sure whether that explains why it's not seeing the change even when you close the "creator" application -- I'd think the modify time, at least, would change when "creator" closes the file.

Comment: When your "CREATOR" application changes the file, can you confirm it changes by opening the file manually and check it, maybe you didn't call `Flush()` on writer stream or so.., another thing is why you set the whole notification filters? you need only a few from them

Comment: I add all because some doesn't work. When I open file, changes are saved. So it isn't problem

Comment: You have set the filter of the `FileSystemWatcher` to `kbd.dbf`, which means you will only be watching **that one file**.

Comment: Yes I know, I want to watch that one file

Comment: @nirmus: Are you sure that the creator program is actually changing the file?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. (I checked it several times..)

Comment: When I set filter to *.* nothing happened too. CREATOR modified the file, but fileSystemWatcher didn't remark it..

Answer (score 0):

Here a few hints that maybe helps you:

1. It doesn't matter if you made the changes `by hand` or by another application "you CREATOR", since when you make them by hand, you actually use some application like "notepad.exe" or something, so that is not really matters.
2. You should set `EnableRaisingEvent` to true "start watching" **after** you set the path and register the event handlers, so the it should be last thing after set all the configurations of the watcher.
3. At your `NotifyFilter` are setting the whole notifications filters which will leads you to receive duplicates notifications some times.
4. Since you only want to watch a specific folder, then you don't have to include sub folders, i.e `fIncludeSubdirectories` should be false.
5. Why you are setting a `SynchronizingObject` to `this`? a better *if you have to anyway* is to take it to a `new object()`.

Comment: this setting was generate by visual studio when I set some property `by mouse click`. Your hints are helpful, but I know it. It doesn't work after change using your hint..

Comment: It doesn't matter, you have set multi flag that will cause you to receive duplicated notifications, like: `NotifyFilters.LastWrite` and `NotifyFilters.Attributes` will receive duplicates notifications when file changes, one for last write and other for attributes...